Unification of Interactions
It has been asked before but with a different aim, and was answered mathematically, while I look for a practical understanding of it. If the Four Foundamental Forces were unified in the first instants after the Big Bang, would it mean that all the four different forces obeyed the same mathematical laws for both formulas and quantity (like for example Gravity being not weak compared to other forces), or actually that was only one single boson that applied all the four forces contemporarily? I mean, let us hypothize a body at actual absolute zero, I know it cannot exist but let's imagine it could: it would not emit any kind of photons. But it would anyway possess a gravitational manifestation. If such a body was to exist (twice absurd since early universe was extremely hot, but please follow my reasoning) in a cosmic age when all forces were unified, would it still emit photons because it has a mass and thus is emitting gravitons which, in times of unified forces, were not existing in themselves but as photons-gravitons&etc? So that hypothetically blocking these photons-gravitons could (we can block photons) prevent from gravitational pull of such body to express itself on sorrounding masses? Was it a practical unification? Or just means that they all acted alike with same numbers in their formulas, like for example canceling the difference between the strenght of electromagnetism and gravitational pull?
I think I got that the answer is the latter: they just worked identically from a mathematical point of view, not that there was only one single boson doing everything at once.
Can anybody confirm or refute such statement of mine?
Second question: if this is correct (identical functioning, not that there was just one single boson) were they interchangeable? Could it be possible in such a setting, for example, to turn a graviton into a photon thus canceling the gravitational field exerted by a mass?
During the electroweak burning, quarks are tought to be turned into leptons, if this is possible, can then be tought that a potential unified force was able to actually turn anything into anything else, like for example a kind of boson into a completely different boson, like for example, turning a photon into a graviton and vice-versa?

Since there is no theory that successfully unifies all the forces, it is difficult to answer this question. We don't know what a theory that can unify the force would look like. So how can we know what a hypothetical body experiencing this unified force would feel?
